# How do I mirror text in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, mirror

How do I mirror text just like [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) in [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox)? Is there [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) that can do this or is it possible with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)?  I'm looking for a true mirror image that I can then manipulate not backwards text.

Comment: You mean like CoverFlow in iTunes?

Comment: Define "just like iTunes".  I am a programmer; I don't use crappy software like iTunes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text/11457128#11457128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin that can create that effect: [FontEffect](http://www.iofo.it/jquery/fonteffect/)

**Edit:** The original links does not work any more but this seems to be the same plugin (untested...): https://code.google.com/p/clapee-shuffle/source/browse/trunk/Test1/js/jquery-fonteffect-1.0.0.js?r=4

Comment: @Nordenheim Thanks, I have found a replacement and although it really is not much of an answer, I'll just leave it just in case somebody finds it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Christian Effenberger's [Reflex](http://www.netzgesta.de/reflex/) library provides a nice degradable reflection effect for images, but not for text.  Depending on the height of the area you wish to reflect you can use the old technique of creating multiple single-pixel-tall divs with with negative top offsets and copies of the original text.  Clunky, but effective.

Answer (score 1):

CSS transforms or HTML5 Canvas are probably your best bet without getting into Java/Flash:
http://webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/

Answer (score 1):

There's JavaScript code to do it.  You could probably look at the code on a site like [Flip Text](http://www.upsidedowntext.com/).

And like charlie said, it's basically a conversion - one character matched with another that looks upside down.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution too:
http://snipplr.com/view/4215/flip-your-text-with-charsets/