# Can you use CSS to mirror/flip text?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use CSS/CSS3 to mirror text?

Specifically, I have this scissors char “✂” (`&#9986;`) that I'd like to display pointing left and not right.

Comment: If the scissors image for some reason doesn't work out for you, I've seen it faked with %< and >%

Comment: See this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433641/flipping-inverting-mirroring-text-using-css-only


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433641/flipping-inverting-mirroring-text-using-css-only

Comment: The answer by Micheal is more accurate. Can you please update the correct answer? Because the answer which you've marked as correct is not mirror but rotation by 180 degrees.

Comment: @PeteWilson, ? Is the ✂ char so common? What's it used for?

Comment: +5 for nice question

Comment: Be aware that the rotation is different depending on the emoji implementation. On Apples emoji set it’s pointing down.

Answer (score 535, accepted):

You can use CSS transformations to achieve this. A horizontal flip would involve scaling the div like this:

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

And a vertical flip would involve scaling the div like this:

```
-moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
-o-transform: scale(1, -1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
transform: scale(1, -1);
```

---

### DEMO:

```css
span{ display: inline-block; margin:1em; } 
.flip_H{ transform: scale(-1, 1); color:red; }
.flip_V{ transform: scale(1, -1); color:green; }
```

```html
<span class='flip_H'>Demo text &#9986;</span>
<span class='flip_V'>Demo text &#9986;</span>
```

Comment: It is certainly the nost standards compliant answer, unfortunately we don't live in a world where this actually works for all use cases yet.

Comment: Could you include the actual browser prefixes in your answer, with the non-prefixed last? The CSS as you gave it does not work.

Comment: @SerranoPereira indeed, thanks for the suggestion. Answer amended.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it is a real mirror. The chosen answer is only a rotate which in the case of asymmetrical anything will not provide a mirror image.

Comment: Possible side-note: Also mirrors padding (`padding-right: 10px;` will show 10px padding on the left), but not margin.

Comment: Note that [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements) like Foundation's suggested <i> tags, unless you also give then display: inline-block.

Answer (score 72):

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

The two parameters are X axis, and Y axis, -1 will be a mirror, but you can scale to any size you like to suit your needs. Upside down and backwards would be `(-1, -1)`.

If you're interested in the best option available for cross browser support back in 2011, see [my older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5406661/1).

Comment: Technically this is not a mirror. its rotated. So it'll only work with some type of elements

Comment: I had some issues in Chrome until I added display: inline-block to my span (using pictos fonts)

Comment: Given that when this question was asked, browser transforms were not widely supported, I would argue that this WAS the right answer. In fact transforms are not supported until IE 9, so I would argue that this is STILL the right answer, for at least a little while longer.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it is not a mirror. It only works in this one case because the symbol given in the example is vertically asymmetrical.

Comment: Although this is useful in itself, it's not the answer to the exact question asked. I found this question through a search engine because I wanted to flip an image horizontally. It's not symmetrical like the OPs scissors.

Comment: previous comments are no longer relevant since the answer now correctly suggests the use of `scale` and not `rotate(-180deg)`

Answer (score 69):

Real mirror:

```css
.mirror{
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 30px;

    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class='mirror'>Mirror Text<span>
```

Comment: You should *always* put the standards-compliant (non-prefixed) property last, so that when the standard is adopted by a browser, it will use the standards-based version instead of the (older, buggier) prefixed version. In this case, that means "transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" should be the *last* property. (Edited the answer to reflect this.)

Comment: I don't know whether this should be on the correct answer or the question but I want to let fontawesome / bootstrap users know about the `fa-flip-horizontal` and `fa-flip-vertical` properties

Comment: Great real answer. However display:block; not necessarily needed.

Comment: yep... display:block; or inline-block is needed

Comment: This was really helpful to keep the correct text orientation of an element's backface when rotated along the Y axis. For ex: ```backface-visibility: visible;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) rotateY(180deg) ;```

Answer (score 15):

You can user either

```
.your-class{ 
      position:absolute; 
      -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); 
      -o-transform: scaleX(-1); 
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); 
      transform: scaleX(-1); 
      filter: FlipH;  
}
```

or

```
 .your-class{ 
  position:absolute;
  transform: rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

Notice that setting `position` to `absolute` is very important! If you won't set it, you will need to set     `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 8):

I cobbled together this solution by scouring the Internet including

- Stack Overflow answers,
- MSDN articles,
- http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/,
- http://caniuse.com/#search=transform,
- http://browserhacks.com/, and
- http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/.

This solution seems to work in all browsers including IE6+, using `scale(-1,1)` (a proper mirror) and appropriate `filter`/`-ms-filter` properties when necessary (IE6-8):

```css
/* Cross-browser mirroring of content. Note that CSS pre-processors
  like Less cough on the media hack. 

  Microsoft recommends using BasicImage as a more efficent/faster form of
  mirroring, instead of FlipH or some kind of Matrix scaling/transform.
  @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
*/

/* IE8 only via hack: necessary because IE9+ will also interpret -ms-filter,
  and mirroring something that's already mirrored results in no net change! */
@media \0screen {
  .mirror {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(mirror=1)";
  }
}
.mirror {
  /* IE6 and 7 via hack */
  *filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(mirror=1);
  /* Standards browsers, including IE9+ */
  -moz-transform: scale(-1,1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1,1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1,1); /* Op 11.5 only */
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1,1);
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's also the `rotateY` for a real mirror one:

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

Which, perhaps, is even more clear and understandable.

**EDIT:** Doesn't seem to work on Opera though… sadly. But it works fine on Firefox. I guess it might required to implicitly say that we are doing some kind of `translate3d` perhaps? Or something like that.

Comment: For those wondering this is a 3D transform. I think it is definitely more readable/understandable than the scale and matrix methods given previously.

Comment: I do not see how a rotation is a mirror - that would only appear to be so in one special case.

Comment: @celsharp it's on the Y axis, so you see the image/element from its back, thus, mirrored.

Answer (score 6):

For cross browser compatibility create this class

```
.mirror-icon:before {
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

And add it to your icon class, i.e.

```
<i class="icon-search mirror-icon"></i>
```

to get a search icon with the handle on the left

Answer (score 4):

you can use 'transform' to achieve this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/aRcQ8/

css:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(-180deg);
```

Comment: I believe this is technically not mirrored (except for some cases only, eg a shape with central symmetry).

Answer (score 3):

Just adding a working demo for horizontal and vertical mirror flip.

```css
.horizontal-flip {
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.vertical-flip {
  -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-flip">
  Hello, World
  <input type="text">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="vertical-flip">
  Hello, World
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

That works fine with font icons like ['s7 stroke icons'](https://hackerthemes.com/charming-pro/docs/icons/stroke7/) and ['font-awesome'](https://fontawesome.com/):

```
.mirror {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

And then on target element:

```
<button>
  <span class="s7-back mirror"></span>
  <span>Next</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one more example how the character could be flipped. Add vendor prefixes if you need ones but for now all modern browsers support unprefixed transform property. The only exception is Opera if Opera Mini mode is enabled (~3% world users).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Text rotation</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .scissors {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: red;
    }
    .original {
      color: initial;
    }
    .flipped {
      transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    }
    .upward {
      transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    }
    .downward {
      transform: rotateZ(90deg);
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Original: <span class="scissors original">&#9986;</span></li>
    <li>Flipped: <span class="scissors flipped">&#9986;</span></li>
    <li>Upward: <span class="scissors upward">&#9986;</span></li>
    <li>Downward: <span class="scissors downward">&#9986;</span></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try box-reflect

```
box-reflect: 20px right;
```

see [CSS property box-reflect compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173666/css-property-box-reflect-compatibility) for more details

Comment: box-reflect is a webkit only property. but i dont think it has a -moz- equivalent.. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173666/css-property-box-reflect-compatibility)..

Comment: also separator should be `:` not `;`

Answer (score 1):

We can make pretty cool text effects using very little code, with [css keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), and its `alternate` property (try removing `alternate` to see the difference):

```css
span {
  font-weight: 1000; font-size: 3.3em;
}
small {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  animation: 1s infinite alternate coolrotate
}

@keyframes coolrotate {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-0.1em, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(-1, 1) translate(0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span>c</span>
  <small>o</small>
  <span>o</span>
  <small>L</small>
  <small>...</small>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me for `<span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span>`

```
display:inline-block;
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=4);
```

just need display:inline-block or block to rotate. So basically first answer is good. But -180 didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

`direction: rtl;` is probably what you are looking for.