# CSS property box-reflect compatibility?

Tags: css

Is there similar property to `-webkit-box-reflect` for the mozilla and other browsers? I could not find on google which other browsers have support for this. So if someone can tell me or give me link, that would be really nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is possible** with not only webkit (latest chrome or safari) but also in latest firefox.

Here is the example: **http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/pgioE**

HTML:

```
<div id="someid">
   <img src="image url" />
<div/>
```

CSS (webkit):

```
#someid {
        /* need some space for the reflection */
        margin-bottom: 120px;
        /* the gradient makes the reflection fade out */
        -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 100%);
}
```

CSS (Firefox - Gecko):

```
#someid {
        position: relative;
        /* need some space for the reflection */
        margin-bottom: 120px;
}

#someid:before {
        content:""; /* needed or nothing will be shown */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 65%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7)) 0px 0px, -moz-element(#someid) 0px -127px no-repeat;
        -moz-transform: scaleY(-1); /* flip the image vertically */
        position:relative;
        height:140px;
        width: 360px; /* should be > image width + margin + shadow */
        top: 247px;
        left:0px;
 }
```

Firefox uses `-moz-element` to do the reflections (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element), whereas webkit uses a proprietary vendor prefix for reflections.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

The `-webkit-box-reflect` property is only supported by webkit browsers, namely Chrome and Safari. As it is a proprietary webkit property, there is no equivalent for other browsers.

The alternative would be to use javascript to create a mirror element with faded opacity.