# How to make a mirror of menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am newbie in CSS coding. Is there any easy option in CSS to make "mirror" of menu which is constructed like below. I would like to get exactly the same menu but in mirror.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="blue"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="red"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="green"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.navbox {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
ul.nav {
    background: url("shadow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 60px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.nav li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
}
.nav li a:hover {background: url("border.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 black;
color: white;
padding: 7px 15px 7px 30px;}
.blue a { background: url("border.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 blue;}
.red a { background: url("border.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 red;}
.green a {background: url("border.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 green;}
```

---

Hello again and thanks for the answers.

It almost solves my problem:

```
.mirror {
    display:block; 
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform:matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

But, is there any option which could avoid "mirroring" of the text? I mean:

```
<li class="red"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="green"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

That text stay without "mirroring"?

Comment: I think this question can help [Can you use CSS to mirror/flip text?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text

Comment: Mahmoud's link will help you, but straight CSS isn't going to do it for you - you'll need to duplicate the DOM structure of your menu, and apply the mirroring CSS to the copy. Can you do a quick photoshop mockup of how you expect this to look?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [blog](http://csscreator.com/node/6494).

This is having the same thing they have discussed.

May be useful for your design

(or)

```
           .rotated{
            -  moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
             -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
             transform: rotate(-180deg);
               filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)
             }
```

Try this out

Answer (score 0):

Try to aply this class to a copy of the menu element:

```
.mirror    {
   -prefix-transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS 3 `transform` tag to rotate elements. Try this:

```
.rotated {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)
}
```