# CSS reverse a whole website (mirror effect) excluding tetand images

Tags: html, css, localization, right-to-left

I just trying to find an creative way to set up a wordpress/prestashop template for RTL languages arabic/hebrew.

I've found this topic.
[Can you use CSS to mirror/flip text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text)

And here is my thought. What if apply scale(-1, 1) for all tags, excluding images and text.

Will it work? Is it any right way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

The link above you posted if I see the accepted answer. that is doing just a rotation effect not actual mirror effect. you are designing the website in Arabic language which start from right to let.

In this case you can this css property in your body tag.

```
body
{direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

For more details you must ***[watch this link](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/)***.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, then closed this question by accepting the answer.