# Mirror or Reverse a given text and set as HTML Title-Tag

Tags: html, title

I need to have HTML title as a mirror image of a text.

For example, if my HTML title is "Paint", then it should be like this image.

[image: Paint_mirror_image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit: By title, I mean the title of the page that is given in HTML TITLE TAG.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text.

Comment: First, its not an image, its a text. Second, I want to mirror the text in the HTML title tag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... I think it's perfectly possible...
Just need the map of `reversed characters` and then change the title with javascript or directly in PHP depending on how you want to do it.

So... if you have the array with the reversed map characters like:
http://txtn.us/data/transforms.js

just need to:

1. use that array to replace each character of the actual title
2. invert the order
3. replace/create the new title tag
4. done

Example (only the reverse part) http://txtn.us/mirror-words

#### Updated

It was a funny proyect so I go further and...
jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/4xyk1ofx/

[image]

Comment: To the `-1 user`... Could you explain why... Do I misunderstood the question or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply CSS to the  element, but not though the style attribute

refer this link >> [**Index of Attributes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) and
[**title Elemet**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE)

example of text flipping using css >> [**TextFlip-Paint**](http://jsfiddle.net/R29xA/85/)

[image: testflip]

I'm not aware of any browser that will apply CSS for the rendering of the title in browser tabs or title bars though.

You can, however, do something like:

```
head {
    display: block;
}
title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<div style="-moz-transform: scaleX(-1); -o-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1); filter: FlipH; -ms-filter: "FlipH";">Paint</div>
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/

Comment: I wanted to do the same in the html title tag. Is that possible?