# How to easily mirror my HTML vertically?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working on the international website now, and one of its' languages is Arabic. Due to Arabic culture, whole interface must be mirrored vertically (obviously to flip sides, not only text direction).

I already tried to use the trick with `transform: rotateY(180deg)` on container and `transform: rotateY(180deg)` on each child node, but got an issue that my interface totally disppeared. Tried to `transform: scale(-1, 1)` with same result. `backface-visibility: visible` added to each node of document.

Do you have any idea how to mirror website interface without writing separate stylesheets and other painful things?

---

OK, I just recreated my problem here, maybe this can help: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ksof29/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use CSS to mirror/flip text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text)

Comment: Did you use backface-visibility?

Comment: @ArjanKnol already tried this, same result

Comment: @Nitesh yes, of couse

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working:

```
html {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
   filter: FlipH;
   -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: `filter: FlipH` doesn't work at all, `transform: scale` gives same result :(

Comment: Unlucky. Can u send me the link?

Comment: did u use all prefixes? on that one?

    html {
      -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
      -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
      -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
      transform: scale(-1, 1);
    }

Comment: here is little example with same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ksof29/1/. Look at list inside section - it's transformed, and on flip it disappears

Comment: i use autoprefixer. However, it doesn't work in Chrome even with -webkit- prefix